# When does __getattribute__ not get involved in attribute lookup?

Tags: python, attributes

Consider the following:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello!'

    def foo(self):
        print 'Foo!'

    def __getattribute__(self, att):
        raise AttributeError()

a = A() # Works, prints "Hello!"
a.foo() # throws AttributeError as expected
```

The implementation of `__getattribute__` obviously fails all lookups. My questions:

- Why is it still possible to instantiate an object? I would have expected the lookup of the `__init__` method itself to fail as well.
- What's the list of attributes that are not subject to `__getattribute__`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The implementation of `__getattribute__` obviously fails all lookups

Let's say it fails for all vanilla lookups.

So how did `__getattribute__` itself get called in the first place since it is also an attribute of the class?

---

An attribute would refer to any name following a dot. So to **get** an **attribute** of a class instance, `__getattribute__` is summoned unconditionally when you try to access that attribute (through dot reference).

However *magic methods* like `__init__` are part of the language construct and so are not directly invoked (via dot reference) since they are implemented as part of the language.

> Why is it still possible to instantiate an object?

When you do:

```
a = A()
```

The `__init__` method gets called behind the scenes, but not via a vanilla *lookup*. The language handles this. Same applies to other methods like `__setattr__`, `__delattr__`, `__getattribute__` also and others.

But if you directly called `__init__`:

```
a.__init__()
```

It would raise an error. Eh, this does not make any sense since the class is already initialized.

More subtly, if you tried to access `__getattribute__` from your class instance via a dot reference:

```
a.__getattribute__
```

it would also raise an `AttributeError`; the language invocation of the same method attempted to lookup on the attribute `__getattribute__`, but failed with error.

---

> What's the list of attributes that are not subject to
>   `__getattribute__`?

Summarily, `__getattribute__` comes play when you try to access any attribute via dot reference. As long as you don't try to explicitly call a *magic method*, `__getattribute__` will not be called.

Comment: It is worth noting that accessing `.__dict__` does not call `__getattribute__()`.

Comment: Ah, I now see the difference.  I thought that it was true even outside of the class body.  I have just done some testing, and it appears that accessing `.__dict__` outside the class body will call `__getattribute__`, but will not call `__getattr__`.  I wonder why they made the distinction.

Comment: @zondo Accessing `self.__dict__` would also require `__getattribute__`. `__getattr__` is only called as a last resort when the attribute is not found via `__getattribute__`

Comment: If you define `__getattr__`, but not `__getattribute__`, then accessing any attribute will result in `__getattr__` being called.  Acessing `__dict__`, however, will not call it.  If you define `__getattribute__`, but not `__getattr__`, it will be called even when accessing `__dict__`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. A reference to where the Python docs state this explicitly would be helpful for future readers.